# R:Copy certain elements from a vector and paste them in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I Have created R-code which produces a result in **Hexadecimal**.
`dput(hexResults)
c("34", "c3", "3b", "7f", "14", "fd", "53", "dc", "ea", "25", 
"e0", "1a", "02", "e1", "67", "27", "34", "c3", "3b", "7f", "14", 
"fd", "53", "dc", "ea", "25", "e0", "1a", "02", "e1", "67", "27"`.

After that, I tried to convert the results in Binary using package **BMS** `hex2bin(hexResults)` `dput(hex2bin(hexResults))
c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1)`.

If you take a closer look you will notice that the first Hexadecimal number(34) converted to binary then 4 zeros `0000` was added then it converted the second number(c3) and again added 4 zeros and so on. I couldn't find the reason Except it could be some sort of padding.

Now, what I'm trying to get is:

- copy the binary number, which is equivalent to the Hex number, and Skip the 4 Zeros that are between numbers.
- Paste the 8 digit binary number in a dataframe.
- Dataframe consists of 8 columns, where each binary number is going to be in a single row (for the whole data). So number of rows will equal to the converted numbers. Digits of the binary number is spread over the 8 columns of each number. The dataframe should be like picture below.
  [image: Expected Dataframe]

I'm thinking to get this by looping over the data, my difficulties in copying selective data from vector to dataframe. Any suggestions using other commands such as paste?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to loop anything. You just can transform the vector into a matrix and save it as a df.

```
vec <- hex2bin(hexResults)
vec <- c(vec, 0, 0, 0, 0) #add last binary that is missing
df <- as.data.frame(matrix(vec, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)) # get into df format
df <- df[, -c(9:12)] #remove binary zeros

df[1:2, ] #check result
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8
1  0  0  1  1  0  1  0  0
2  1  1  0  0  0  0  1  1
```

Comment: Thanks. Works for me.